# Why is `eas` ignoring my `package.json` when building my project? Specifically, the `bundleIdentifier` is not being found

Tags: expo, eas

When running `eas build --platform ios` from Expo, I get the following error `your project must have a bundleidentifier set in the expo config (app.json or app.config.js).`, but I do have a `bundleIdentifier` set in `app.json`, under `expo.ios.bundleIdentifier`.

Answer (score 1):

[This guide](https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/eas-build-archive.md) was helpful in debugging.

In my case, it turned out my `app.json` file was in my `.gitignore` (because it's code genned from other files in my project so I don't want it committed), and `eas` doesn't upload files that are `.gitignore`d.

I therefore solved it by introducing a `.easignore` in the root of my directory that did not exclude `app.json`.